# Dont reload webview video on rotate

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview that is showing an embedded video.  When the device is rotated, I can prevent the entire page from being reloaded with:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    webView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

However, since I am playing a video in this webview, the video does not continue playing.  Instead, it will load the video as if it has not started playing.  How can I rotate the screen but continue the video like nothing happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this in manifest.xml

```
 upto API level 12

       <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
 </activity>

after apl level 12,

       <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
      </activity>
```

Comment: Looks like I was forgetting 'screenSize'.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question how to pause video playing a webview.  These settings changes in the manifest are only to allow rotation.

Comment: `screenSize` yeah! `screenSize` yeah! `screenSize` yeah! thank you!

Comment: @JPM what do you mean?... we talk about saving video on rotation. There is no question "how to pause"...

Comment: From his question "How can I rotate the screen but continue the video like nothing happened?"  It still has to pause the video then pick it back at the same spot.

Comment: yeah this worked for me, thanks you save my time! bro

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rajendra . Searching for this from 3 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

e.g.

```
<activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="Activity"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

Comment: I already have this in my Manifest.  Note that this is a webview and not the android media player class.